# What's the NestJS equivalent of Service.new(param) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am moving from RoR to NestJS and have a question

In RoR we can declare a Service Object like this

```
class UserService 
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def complex_logic
    # do a complex logic using @user instance variable
  end
end
```

In NestJS we can also declare a Service (and of course inject it correctly)

```
export class UserService {
  constructor()

  public complexLogic() {
  
}
```

What do I need to do in NestJS if I want to init an UserService with an user param? I tried to declare a param in service's constructor but it's not working

Comment: user param? maybe you are looking for controller.

Answer (score 1):

To add parameters to [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) you just add them to the constuctor method:

```
export class UserService {
  #user;  // defines a private field
  constructor(user) {
    this.#user = user;
  }

  public complexLogic() {
    console.log(this.#user);
  }
}
```

This really has everything to do with the language and very little to do with NestJS.